# Can't find what package to install to get a proper Qtmultmedia gstreamer backend

Tags: package-management, 18.04, python3, qt5, pyqt5

In a new shiny ubuntu **18.04**, I am trying to use a python3/pyqt5 script that use **QtMultimedia**.

It was working fine in 17.10. And now even after installing a bunch of package, I still can't get it to work. I have the following error when a QMediaplayer is instanciated:

```
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

I assume it is an error because Qt5 and QtMultimedia can't find a proper backend registered right ?

I have all these package installed:

```
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0 1.14.0-1
gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64 1.14.0-2ubuntu1
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0:amd64 3.0.26-1
gstreamer1.0-fluendo-mp3:amd64 0.10.32.debian-1
gstreamer1.0-gl:amd64 1.14.0-2ubuntu1
gstreamer1.0-libav:amd64 1.14.0-1
gstreamer1.0-packagekit 1.1.9-1ubuntu2
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad:amd64 1.14.0-1ubuntu1
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:amd64 1.14.0-2ubuntu1
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps 1.14.0-2ubuntu1
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good:amd64 1.14.0-1ubuntu1
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly:amd64 1.14.0-1
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio:amd64 1.14.0-1ubuntu1
gstreamer1.0-python3-plugin-loader 1.14.0-1
gstreamer1.0-qt5:amd64 1.14.0-1ubuntu1
gstreamer1.0-tools 1.14.0-1
gstreamer1.0-vaapi:amd64 1.14.0-1
gstreamer1.0-x:amd64 1.14.0-2ubuntu1
libgstreamer1.0-0:amd64 1.14.0-1
libgstreamer-gl1.0-0:amd64 1.14.0-2ubuntu1
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64 1.14.0-1ubuntu1
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:amd64 1.14.0-2ubuntu1
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0:amd64 1.14.0-1ubuntu1
libqt5core5a:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5dbus5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5designer5:amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
libqt5glib-2.0-0:amd64 1.2.0-5
libqt5gstreamer-1.0-0:amd64 1.2.0-5
libqt5gui5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5help5:amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
libqt5multimedia5:amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
libqt5multimediawidgets5:amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
libqt5network5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5opengl5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5printsupport5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5qml5:amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
libqt5quick5:amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
libqt5sql5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5svg5:amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
libqt5test5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5widgets5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libqt5x11extras5:amd64 5.9.5-0ubuntu1
libqt5xml5:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer 1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1
python3-pyqt5 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2
python3-pyqt5.qtmultimedia 5.10.1+dfsg-1ubuntu2
qt5-gtk-platformtheme:amd64 5.9.5+dfsg-0ubuntu1
qtgstreamer-plugins-qt5:amd64 1.2.0-5
```

When I compare this list with the one I got on 17.10, I don't seem to miss any. So ?

I run the script with `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1` set, and I didn't see any error or problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just [solved my issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1035561/which-gstreamer-in-pyqt5/1038195#1038195) so maybe it will help you too.

Copy-past below:

The problem was that I had few two versions of `PyQt5` and `sip` installed for Python3. One was in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` and the other in `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-pacages/`. Completely deleting `.local` versions helped.

Comment: I have no version of `PyQt5` nor `sip` in `./local/...` so this does not help me

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this, here is the proper setup which will build Qt 5.11.2 as non-root,
then install pyqt 5.11.2 with GStreamer 1.0 support on Ubuntu 18.04 into a **virtual environment** using python >= 3.6:

1. [Install gstreamer1.0](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html)
2. Install pulse (This is required so QMultimediaWidgets is build) `sudo apt install libpulse-dev`
3. [Download Qt 5.11.2](https://www.qt.io/qt5-11)
4. Make the downloaded file executable and run it (`chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-3.0.5-online.run`). Click through the wizard. I'm assuming you are installing to `$HOME/Qt`
5. Create a virtual environment `python -m venv venv`.
6. [Download SIP 4.19.12](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/sip/download) and unpack
7. [Download pyqt 5.11.2](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5) and unpack
8. Activate your environment `source venv/bin/activate`
9. Install SIP:

   - Go inside the SIP folder
   - Tell it to use your virtual env `python configure.py -d ../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages`
   - `make -j4`
   - `make install`
   - Build a private copy for Qt: `python configure.py -d ../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages --sip-module PyQt5.sip --no-tools`
   - `make -j4`
   - `make install`
10. Install PyQt:

    - Go inside the PyQt folder
    - Tell it which qmake, python and sip to use `python configure.py --destdir ../venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages --qmake ~/Qt/5.11.2/gcc_64/bin/qmake --sip ../venv/bin/sip`
    - `make -j12`
    - `make install`

That should be it now. Based on http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/installation.html, http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html
and a lot of trial and error. If something does not work, I recommend using `--verbose` during the configuration step of PyQt.