# Which Gstreamer in PyQt5?

Tags: python, gstreamer, pyqt5

On Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 whenever I'm trying to use `QMediaPlayer` I'm being prompted with no service.

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtMultimedia
>>> qtm = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer()
defaultServiceProvider::requestService(): no service found for - "org.qt-project.qt.mediaplayer"
```

The Internet suggests installing some `gstreamer` packages but it doesn't say which. How can I figure out which package is needed?

It seems that by default Ubuntu comes with `Gstreamer1.0` and I can run `gst-play-1.0 FILEPATH`. Any chance that `gstreamer-0.10` is needed instead? How can I set reverse the dependency?

Packages which I have installed

```
notlaptop@laptop$ apt list --installed | grep gstream 
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-alsa/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0/bionic,now 3.0.26-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-gl/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-packagekit/bionic,now 1.1.9-1ubuntu2 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base-apps/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-qt5/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-tools/bionic,now 1.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
gstreamer1.0-x/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-gl1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-opencv1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.14.0-2ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer-plugins-good1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.14.0-1ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-0/bionic,now 1.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
libgstreamer1.0-dev/bionic,now 1.14.0-1 amd64 [installed]
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer/bionic,now 1:6.0.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed]
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1034114/350004

Comment: Just noticed that it works on my Python2 but not on Python3. No idea why, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had few two versions of `PyQt5` and `sip` installed for Python3. One was in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/` and the other in `~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-pacages/`. Completely deleting `.local` versions helped.

That, and installing everything that I could find with `gstreamer`.